# Join multiple tables using latest records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables.  1 is FORUM, 2 is CURRENT and 3 is ARCHIVE.

- FORUM contains metadata about forums where users post comments, with one row per forum.
- CURRENT contains metadata about "current" entries from all the forums, 1 row per entry.
- ARCHIVE contains metadata about "archived" entries from all the forums, one row per entry.

Each forum can have entries in both the CURRENT and ARCHIVE tables.  CURRENT and ARCHIVE are identical.

The columns of interest in FORUM are `FORUM_NAME` and `FORUM_NUMBER`.

The columns of interest in CURRENT and ARCHIVE are `ENTRY_NUMBER`, `FORUM_NUMBER`, `MOD_DATE`.

The query below, returns the most recent MOD_DATE for each forum that has rows in the CURRENT table.

```
select max(c.mod_date), f.forum_name, f.forum__number 
from forum f, current c 
where f.forum_number=c.forum_number
group by f.forum_name, f.forum_number order by max(c.mod_date) desc;
```

How do I configure this to query both the current AND archive tables, and return the single most recent mod_date for each forum regardless of which table has the most recent mod_date for that forum?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to have union of both tables queries as inner select and then order by in outer select. Imho this shall be doable.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, but what would that look like?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another sample for better approach to denormalizing a table for the internet.  I would add two columns to your forum table for LatestCurrent and LatestArchive.  As entries are added into each respective, have a trigger that updates the forum table with the respective column of latest date.  You might even want the ID of the latest current / archive so you can immediately join to those tables without having to do a MAX() each time to query.

Now, that being said, you would need something like

```
select 
      f.forum_name, 
      f.forum__number,
      case when CurMax.maxCurrent >= ArchMax.maxArchive
           then CurMax.maxCurrent
           else ArchMax.maxArchive end as MaxDate,
      case when CurMax.maxCurrent >= ArchMax.maxArchive
           then "Current"
           else "Archive" end as MaxSource
   from 
      forum f
         LEFT JOIN ( select c.forum_number, 
                            max(c.mod_date) maxCurrent
                        from current c
                        group by c.forum_number ) CurMax
            on f.forum_number = CurMax.forum_number
         LEFT JOIN ( select a.forum_number, 
                            max(a.mod_date) maxArchive
                        from archive a
                        group by a.forum_number ) ArchMax
            on f.forum_number = ArchMax.forum_number
   order by
      CurMax.maxCurrent DESC
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the option of changing the tables.  I have to work with what I have.  Thanks.

Comment: @user3352599, that is why I still supplied the query on what you have.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to suggest I wasn't considering your query.  Just pointing out that I couldn't mod the tables.  I ran your query and it almost gets me there.  It returns one row for every forum, with columns for max mod_date for both current AND archive.  I need to go a step further and have it tell me just the max mod_date period, whether it's current OR archive, rather than having to manually look at the two columns and determine which one is more recent.  Does that make sense?  Hope I explained adequately.  Again, thanks!  This is really close and puts me on the path.

Comment: @user3352599, revised query to get the largest, but Oracle does have a GREATEST() function, but I did with case/when so you could also see the correlated which table the greatest date came from for later retrieval purposes.

Comment: @user3352599, great... check help / tour for etiquette.  Mark answers as up if good, check if solution so others don't keep trying to offer solutions to what has already been solved.